# My VBA code is not uploading a csv file to ADLS in Azure

Tags: excel, vba, azure, azure-blob-storage

I've a code where I'm trying to upload a csv file into a container in Azure ADLS by HTTP request. Unfortunately I'm not getting the expected result. My code es as follow:

```
Sub DataUpload_ADLS()


    Dim k As Integer
    Dim CSVFilePath As String
    Dim BlobServiceURL As String
    Dim ContainerName As String
    Dim BlobName As String
    Dim SAS_Token As String
    Dim HTTPReq As Object


    CSVFilePath = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\test.csv"

    ' Define your Azure ADLS Storage URL
    BlobServiceURL = "https://mystorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/"
    ContainerName = "data"
    BlobName = "test.csv"
    

    ' Specify your SAS Token here (including the leading '?')
    SAS_Token = "?sp=r&st=2023-09-20T22:32:18Z&..."

    ' Combine the URL components
    Dim UploadURL As String
    UploadURL = BlobServiceURL & ContainerName & "/" & BlobName & SAS_Token

    ' Create an HTTP request object
    Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

    ' Read the CSV file data
    Dim FileData As String
    Open CSVFilePath For Binary As #1
    FileData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , FileData
    Close #1

    ' Send a PUT request to upload the file to Azure Blob Storage
    HTTPReq.Open "PUT", UploadURL, False
    HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"
    HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "x-ms-blob-type", "BLockblob"
    HTTPReq.send FileData

End Sub
```

I'm not pretty sure if Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0") code line is correct, I've configured my references as follow:

[image]

The main problem is that the code is not uploading any file to the ADLS and  my code doesn't send me any error when I run it. Intesad, once it finished and I go to check out my ADLS I got next message:

[image]

Could you guide me? what do I neet to upload the file properly and not make a lot of requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

In my environment, I configured my reference as same as you like below:

[image]

Now, I'm inserting the same code into my module and running it in my VBA explorer and the code executed successfully like below.

**Code:**

```
Sub DataUpload_ADLS()


    Dim k As Integer
    Dim CSVFilePath As String
    Dim BlobServiceURL As String
    Dim ContainerName As String
    Dim BlobName As String
    Dim SAS_Token As String
    Dim HTTPReq As Object

    ' local path
    CSVFilePath = "C:\Users\xxxx\xxx\xxx\rndm.csv"

    ' Define your Azure ADLS Storage URL
    BlobServiceURL = "https://yourstorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/"
    ContainerName = "test"
    BlobName = "test.csv"
    

    ' Specify your SAS Token here (including the leading '?')
    SAS_Token = "?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwdlacupyx&se=2023-09-21T13:57:24Z&st=2023-09-21T05:57:24Z&spr=https&sig=8xxx"

    ' Combine the URL components
    Dim UploadURL As String
    UploadURL = BlobServiceURL & ContainerName & "/" & BlobName & SAS_Token

    ' Create an HTTP request object
    Set HTTPReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")

    ' Read the CSV file data
    Dim FileData As String
    Open CSVFilePath For Binary As #1
    FileData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , FileData
    Close #1

    ' Send a PUT request to upload the file to Azure Blob Storage
    HTTPReq.Open "PUT", UploadURL, False
    HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"
    HTTPReq.setRequestHeader "x-ms-blob-type", "BLockblob"
    HTTPReq.send FileData
    
    MsgBox "File uploaded successfully."
End Sub
```

[image]

> Note: Make sure you using the Correct **`SAS-token`**

You can get the SAS token from the portal.

***Storage account -> sharedaccesssignature -> check the required permission -> generate sas token -> copy the sas token.***

[image]

If you are still not able to upload you can use the error handling in to your code:

```
' Error handling
    On Error Resume Next
    HTTPReq.send FileData
    If HTTPReq.Status <> 201 Then
        MsgBox "Error " & HTTPReq.Status & ": " & HTTPReq.statusText
    Else
        MsgBox "File uploaded successfully."
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
```

**Portal:**

Now, I checked in my portal and I can able to see csv file in the portal.

[image]